# How to ping in C++/Qt without to use a QProcess?

Tags: qt, network-programming, qt5, qtnetwork

I would like ping an ip address in my Qt Application before to launch an external program.

I would like code a ping class without to use ping.exe (and execute a process). The problem is when I "ping 127.0.0.1", it takes 3+ seconds to finish the (ping) process on windows. I need only a fast check (less than 500 ms) before to execute (instantly) my external program.

I would like use QNetwork or something similar.

Comment: I think it takes several seconds, because `ping` utility sends multiple echo requests. You can configure it to send only one package, like: `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1`. The process exits instantly.

Comment: One possibility is as vahancho says to reduce to number of tries and stick with 'ping', another one would be to use ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050(v=vs.85).aspx) and implement it for yourself.

Comment: I can't figure out why you want to ping an IP address, if you want to check connections. There may be  other better solutions to resolve this request.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using platform depended code within your Qt Application you may check:

https://evileg.com/en/post/167/

for an example using ICMP echo API on windows and

https://noping.cc/

for liboping, a Linux C library to generate ICMP echo requests.